# questions re migration antlr3 to antlr4 (apache pig)

Tags: antlr4

I am writing a translator for apache pig, I want to use antlr4 but the current pig lexer/grammar is antlr3, so am migrating syntax to antlr4.

Apache PIG github repo: [[https://github.com/apache/pig/tree/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/parser]](https://%5Bhttps://github.com/apache/pig/tree/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/parser%5D)

Question is regarding the IDENTIFIER definition in QueryLexer.g line 354 - what does this mean?

```
354,359c319
< IDENTIFIER
<     @after {
<         if("null".equalsIgnoreCase(getText())){
<             state.type = NULL;
<         }
<     } : ( ID DCOLON ) => ( ID DCOLON IDENTIFIER ) | ID
```

thanks v much for your time on this.

mr

Comment: The `@after` code is to alter some state of variables in the parser class (all that `@member` code in the grammar). It's hard to say whether that affects the parse or it's just for tree construction. The only way to know for sure is to run the Antlr3 tool on the code and find that action code. My guess it occurs just be fore returning from the LL parse method. The `( ... ) => ( ... )` code in the rule is a syntactic predicate. Antlr4 now looks ahead to determine which alt to take, whether `ID DCOLON IDENTIFIER` or just `ID`. You can remove the useless parens of `(ID DCOLON IDENTIFIER)`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments: the `( ... ) =>` is a syntactic predicate in v3. It was a way of performing some look ahead before actually committing to a certain path. Since v4 parsing/tokenization algorithms are more advanced to v3's, there is not need in v4's parser and lexer rules to perform them manually.

So the v3 syntax:

```
IDENTIFIER
    @after {
        if("null".equalsIgnoreCase(getText())){
            state.type = NULL;
        }
    } : ( ID DCOLON ) => ( ID DCOLON IDENTIFIER ) | ID
      ;
```

can be rewritten for v4 as follows:

```
NULL
 : [nN] [uU] [lL]
 ;

IDENTIFIER
 : ID ( DCOLON IDENTIFIER )?
 ;
```

There is no need to change the type of `IDENTIFIER` if it equals `"null"` as long as you define a `NULL` token *before* the `IDENTIFIER` token.

Comment: Thanks, i re-wrote the initial description to make it clearer, no further comment at this time, thnx again, mr